# How to select lines/edges that overlap with a line layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlay, network-analysis

I am calculating the shortest path in `QGIS` using the `openrouteservice` API. From the returned route, I would like to calculate the length of segments that are paved and those that are not paved.

Since the returned route from the API doesn't contain this information, I would like to overlay this route with my road network data that has these road surface details.

The problem is that when I run the `select by location` operation (intersect, overlap, or touch), the corresponding road segments are selected but also the other segments that just cross the route are selected.
How can I address this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [explode your lines](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisexplodelines), so each segment is created as a separate line. Like this, each line has only two vertices. In this way, you can select those lines that overlap the paved or unpaved parts of the road and calculate the accumulated/aggregated sum.

If you don't want to create a new layer, you can do the explode process and calculations also directly with QGIS expressions: Overlay the centroid of the exploded segements with the road layer and check if at this point, the road is paved or not (based on attribute value). Take the centroid because to avoid wrong results where paved/unpaved lines connect. I also applied a small buffer of 0.1 in case both layers do not overlap perfectly (to correct rounding errors or CRS issues).

*Road layer: blue=paved, red=unpaved; the length of the yellow path (one single feature) is calculated in two parts for paved/unpaved parts of intersecting road:*
[image]

The expression looks like this - replace `road` and `paved` with the names you have and `true` with the value of the `paved` field:

```
array_sum(
    array_foreach(
        geometries_to_array(
            segments_to_lines ($geometry)
        ),
        if (
            intersects (
                centroid (@element), 
                buffer(
                    overlay_nearest(
                        'road',  -- change layername
                        $geometry,
                        filter:= "paved" = true  -- change fieldname
                    )[0],
                    0.1
                )
            ), 
            length (@element),
            0
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I really like this answer. I am yet to test it but it already looks right in my mind. So, I marked it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I have now tested this answer and it works.
Steps:

`0.` Reproject both layers to the same "projected" CRS

`1.` Explode the road network data

`2.` Get the centroids of the exploded road network data (add a spatial index)

`3.` Add a slight buffer to the route layer

`4.` Perform a "select by location" to get the centroids that overlap with the buffered route layer and export them into a separate layer

`5.` Add a slight buffer to the selected centroids layer

`6.` Perform a "select by location" operation to get roads segments that overlap with the buffered selected centroids

Comment: @FaustinGashakamba  I'm not sure if there is no missunderstanding. You don't have to reproduce this step by step with processing tools in QGIS. You can simply use the expression I posted, it does all these at one. These steps were just to show how the expression works.

Comment: No, there is no misunderstanding here. I just wanted to test the process. Ultimately, I want to implement this in `R` as part of a `shiny` app I am building. The app will accept coordinates of various destinations in a CSV file, calculates the shortest route using the `openrouteservice` API, compares the returned route with the OSM road network data, and returns statistics about length of travel on paved road, unpaved road, etc.